# Best tool for live editing SCSS in a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

I used to use CSSEdit to override the CSS stylesheets for my Rails apps and make changes without having to constantly hit save and refresh. Is there an equivalent tool to live preview SCSS?

Answer (score 0):

Check out LiveReload: http://livereload.com/